# Uncaught NoElError: An 'el' must be specified for a region

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to use this code for view animation and calling it `BaseView`:

https://gist.github.com/brian-mann/3947145

then extending view like this:

```
define(['underscore',
    'handlebars',
    'views/BaseView',
    'text!templates/components/login.tmpl'
], function (
    _,
    Handlebars,
    BaseView,
    loginTemplate
) {
    'use strict';

    var LoginView, errorMap;

    LoginView = BaseView.extend({

        compiledTemplate: Handlebars.compile(loginTemplate),

        events: {
        'submit #loginForm': 'login'
        },

        initialize : function(options){
             this.proxyLoginSuccess = options.loginSuccess;
           this.errorMap = options.errorMap;
        }...
    });

    return LoginView;
});
```

It is giving me this error: `Uncaught NoElError: An 'el' must be specified for a region.`

I tried to remove  `this.ensureEl();` but doesn't make any difference. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be unclear about some Marionette concepts. The code you linked isn't a view, it's a Marionette Region, and is therefore used to `show` views, not to be extended from as in your code. This is how you would use it (e.g.):

```
myApp.addRegions({
  fadeRegion: FadeTransitionRegion.extend({
    el: "#some-selector"
  })
});
```

Then, you instantiate a view instance and show it:

```
var myView = new LoginView({
  el: "#another-selector"
});
myApp.fadeRegion.show(myView);
```

In any case, your view needs to have an `el` attribute defined, either in the view definition, or when it gets instantiated (as above).

If you're still confused about the attributes and specifying them in the view definition or at run time, I'd suggest you read the [free preview](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) to my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) where it's explained in more detail.